# Can't fetch specific content out of some complicated html elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

I've written a script to parse some specific content from a webpage. The content are static and using requests module I can reach them. The problem is that the content I wish to grab are within some html elements which are not conventionally formatted.

What my script can grab are the titles containing `Mondays December 26th 2016 Horse Racing Tips` and so on. The word `Mondays` and the year `2016` always appear in each title.

Now, I want to grab the content under different ***Race tips*** like `Sunshine Coast Race Tips`. There are more than one race tips under each `Mondays`.

One such Race tips:

```
Sunshine Coast Race Tips:

Race 1: 7, 5, 4, 3 - Winner (1) $1.30 Exacta $1.90 Trifecta $4.10
Race 2: 2, 4, 3, 8 - Winner (1) $3.40 Exacta $62.70 Trifecta $116.10 First 4 $158.80
Race 3: 4, 10, 5, 13 - 2nd and 4th - Loss
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.freehorseracingtipsaustralia.com/mondays-horse-racing-results-2016"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
root = fromstring(res.text)
for item in root.xpath("//b[starts-with(.,'Mondays')]"):
    print(item.text_content())
```

***How can I achieve that?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get race tips

```
for item in root.xpath('''(//div[b/font[.="Today's Race Tips:"]])[1]/following-sibling::div/b'''):
    print(item.text_content())
```

Comment: I knew there are hopes as long as you are online @sir Andersson. I still have one more requirement. I wanted to get the titles as in `Mondays December 26th 2016 Horse Racing Tips` under which the tips are displayed.

Comment: @asmitu , if you need tips for first block only, try updated. Did you mean that?

Comment: Nope sir. I meant, there are multiple tips under each title out of several titles containing `Mondays`.

Comment: Your xpath can fetch, i think, all the tips. All I need to do now is get all the titles connected to different tips.

Comment: @asmitu , do you mean you want to include `"Mondays December 19th 2016 Horse Racing Tips:"` to output?

Comment: There are several `Mondays` like that such as `Mondays January 4th 2016 Horse Racing Tips:
Mondays January 11th 2016 Horse Racing Tips:
Mondays January 18th 2016 Horse Racing Tips:` and so on. I wanted to get all the titles along with the race tips. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @asmitu, I tried to make XPath more generic, but the HTML is just awful: each block with tips created by its own rule with no common logic... The same data might be colored differently, it might be bold, might be not bold, the same text might appear as `<span><b><font>text</font></b></span>` and might be `<font><b>text</b></font>`... I guess it might take several hours to define generic XPath... And I'm afraid it will be totally unreadable with dozens predicates. You can unaccept the answer - maybe someone else will find proper solution...

Comment: What you have done so far is incredible. I would not imagine that I could come up thus far. The html is really horrible. As for the unacceptance: I would accept your answer twice if i had options. Thanks and much appreciated sir.